# Is it possible to take a screenshot in Recovery Mode?

Tags: macos, keyboard, screen-capture

Or, anywhere outside "userspace?" For example, the login screen, or in Single User Mode.

Comment: Highlighted Terminal text can be exported with SHIFT+CMD+S. May need to mount "Macintosh HD" disk if you want to save to your Documents or Desktop folders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most definitely can do a screen capture from Recovery.

1. Boot into Recovery
2. Open the Terminal from the Utilities menu
3. In Terminal type:

   ```
   /Volumes/name_of_HD/usr/sbin/screencapture -s /Volumes/name_of_HD/Users/name_of_user/Desktop/name_for_file.png
   ```

You will get crosshairs so you can select what you want a screenshot of (like CMD-Shift-4)

name_of_HD=whatever the name of the HD is
name_of_user=any user on the system
name_for_file.png=whatever you want to name the file

When you login as that user, the screen capture will be waiting on your Desktop.

Comment: This use of Terminal automatically mounts the filesystem as read/write which prevents the saving of files using the default keys.

Comment: Under macOS Sierra, it seems that all you can screenshot is the contents of the Terminal window.

There does not appear to be a way to interact with the interface whilst the screenshot crosshairs are present nor does multitasking appear to be possible whilst booted to the Recovery System.

Comment: You can't leave the terminal window, to screenshot anything else tho.

Comment: May need to mount "Macintosh HD" drive first. Even so, in Catalina 10.15.6 I was unable to successfully run `screencapture` ("could not find image").

Answer (score 6):

Where OS X is booted but you can't take a screenshot because you're not logged in (e.g. the login screen, lock screen) you can take a screenshot over SSH. Connect over SSH to your Mac and run…

```
sudo screencapture /path/to/screenshot.png
```

Where OS X isn't displaying a GUI (e.g. single user mode, boot sequence), you can't take a screenshot. This doesn't apply to virtual machines though, if you're determined to get a screenshot.

Comment: In Recovery, the filesystems are mounted read only, which makes the key shortcuts not work. See the Terminal utility to mount a writeable filesystem and [save the pictures from the command line](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/210583/5472).